# dynamic sub domains

Tags: php

I want to show user's mini-website on the server by creating dynamic subdomains.

The re-write rule is written as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourwebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.yourwebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path_to_your_site/public_html/app/test/home.php?url=%1
```

In the home.php page the web.css file is included as shown below:

But the CSS is not getting applied on home.php page due to css file path problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using another subdomain for those files, for example `static.yourwebsite.com`.
If I am not mistaken, you would then have to add this line to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static\.yourwebsite.com
```